# Is there a fully implemented REST javascript client?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, schema

I've been experimenting with and researching javascript clients for RESTful web services. Just about everything I've seen seems to be limited to the recreating model definitions in the client and doing CRUD on simple (non-related) models.

What I'm Looking For

- Ability to dynamically create models (and/or proxies and/or stores) in the client given a URI to the JSONREST schema provided by the server API
- Ability to handle relations natively (that is, without creating a bunch of custom functions or overriding much built-in functionality). I'm talking about 1->n, 1->1, n->1 and n->m relations.
- Ability to work relatively well with a full feature client framework like ExtJS or Dojo.

What I've Tried

- ExtJS 4.1: Great widget set, able to do completely programmatic layout, 'ajax'/'rest' proxies work out-of-the-box for simple models. No IRC or dev community that I can find, limited responsiveness on GPL forums.
- Dojo [current]: Needs custom overriding to JsonRestStore to function with basic models. Great widgets, difficuly to completely avoid html.
- I've also looked at various jquery based tools and a little at backbone.js (http://backbonejs.org is down at the moment.). The jquery stuff seems utterly disjointed to me. If there are good jquery REST tools, I'm open to them, I just need pointers to documentation on how to develop coherent and manageable apps with them.

Basic Goal

- Developing web client apps that are maintainable over time and are "DRY". That is, there is as little copy-pasting of {param1: 'asdf', param2: 30, ...} throughout related "classes". Ideally, if it is defined on the server, the client should get it from the REST API. If it is defined in the client, other parts of the client should be able to inherit/extend that definition.

Another way of saying it:

- Most JS Frameworks follow the MVC pattern. Which, to me, is silly since my "M" is already on the server along with some of the "C". I want my client to be a "Vc", to only recreate as much of the server-side model as is necessary for asynchronous operation focusing on UI presentation and user actions. Which means that ideally none of the "M" in "MVC" will be hard coded into the client.

Is there a full featured javascript REST client that someone can point me towards. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A few links you most likely want to look at:

**Alternative URL for Backbonejs.org**: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

As you may know, Backbone creates Objects like Collections and Models based on your data.

**Relational mapping**: https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/

If you want to have relational data mapping in Backbone, follow the link above

**JSON Schema Validator**: https://github.com/garycourt/JSV

this is handy if you're worried about making sure you adhere to a certain JSON Schema, you can extend Backbone.js to validate a model client-side by overriding the `validate` method.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at the backbone github repo, but I was really hoping to look at some of their tuts and examples. I know that some of the tastypie folks recommend backbone, which matters since I like tastypie and django on the server. I'll look through you other links right now. Any idea how backbone integrates with either ExtJS or Dojo as a UI framework?

Comment: The tutorials and examples are on their github wiki, kind of hidden away from the official documentation: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Tutorials%2C-blog-posts-and-example-sites

Comment: Ahh... Cool. backbone-relational look excellent.

Comment: Regarding JSONREST schemas, am I nuts in wanting to only define the models on the server? Are the schemas used, in practice, only for validation as opposed to model inference?

Comment: as with everything software, it really depends on your requirements. Validating your data against a particular schema client-side AND server-side will benefit you in the end in terms of User Experience because you won't need a lengthy round-trip request. Nothing stops you from writing an exporter to create client-side versions of your json schema. I use JSV in a few cases and it's just really handy at times.

Answer (score 2):

Check out my Javascript JSON-Hyper-Schema client. It dynamically builds an HTML client app using Angular, by parsing the Schema provided at a given resources endpoint with the OPTIONS method.

https://github.com/bpanahij/passportedu_schema/tree/master/client

I have been working on a HATEOAS (Hypermedia as the engine of application state) API, using JSON Hyper Schema.
You can go to the URL below, browse around, register, login and do some actions.

Check it out, here:
http://direct.psprt.com:8081/

I also open sourced my actual API code thus far:
https://github.com/bpanahij/passportedu_schema

Feel free to take a look, borrow, and comment.

[JSON Hyper Schema][1] (See Also [JSON-Schema][2])

Comment: the links are broken

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/avoidwork/abaaso, I've heard nice things about it.

Comment: Look like it might have potential someday. Right now, there is very little documentation, no info on relations and no info on integration with anything other than the html DOM. Great for lightweight tasks. Does not look like what I need for maintainability in a moderately complex app. Thanks, though.

Comment: I think the misconception you have is that it's a plugin for other frameworks, it is used in lieu of ExtJS or Dojo. For your purposes, you'd probably be focused on the data store https://github.com/avoidwork/abaaso/wiki/data, and maybe the client methods.

Comment: Well, I looked at it more thoroughly tonight. I've got to say that I really like the emphasis on getting REST right. The reason that I referred to it in terms of integration with Ext or Dojo (or even JQueryUI once it matures) is that is a core requirement of mine. If you know of examples of abaaso use as a data layer with an integrated UI toolkit, I'd love to see.

Comment: if you have any questions ping me on twitter or through github. the documentation is lacking; it's on my "todo" list to flesh it out more. you can load it with any framework/lib and leverage only the parts you need. i'm doing that with filetrek.com, but that's not really public facing work. i've done a few small proofs using it, but i'm generally lacking time. it is immature, but it's nearly grown up.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. I might just take you up on it.

Comment: i forgot to mention, it's n-n or n-1 depending on the data you consume.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a whole framework, give this a try: https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest It's quite new so please post issues, bugs, feature requests !

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with finding a good client library is that we (as in the web community) don't yet have a fully fleshed and complete understanding of REST and how to build a SERVER library.

Techniques such as HAL (http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) may offer the best direction forward.  When you have a set of APIs that commit to HATEOAS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) and that really work in such a way as to allow hyperlinking to drive the application then you have a means to build VERY light weight front ends that don't need to rebuild every object, and rethink every business rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try [restful.js](https://github.com/marmelab/restful.js). The expressive syntax allows for resource nesting, builds up on promises, and stays out of your way. It's inspired by Restangular, only it is standalone.

Disclaimer: we wrote it.